# Request permission to use Face ID/Touch ID programmatically

Tags: ios, biometrics, touch-id, face-id

Is there a way to request permission for Face ID/Touch ID programmatically? I know that permission for Face ID is triggered the first time you call

```
evaluatePolicy(_ policy: LAPolicy, localizedReason: String, reply: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Swift.Void)
```

I have seen apps that have a custom screen with a toggle option...and never show the iOS Modal for permissions and they do not trigger biometrics right away.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kNOE.png

Comment: Did you get any way to request permission programmatically?